Debian - Unattended upgrades isn't upgrading packages
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
    // Codename based matching:
    // This will follow the migration of a release through different
    // archives (e.g. from testing to stable and later oldstable).
    // Software will be the latest available for the named release,
    // but the Debian release itself will not be automatically upgraded.
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security";
    "origin=CrowdSec,label=CrowdSec";
    "origin=Docker,label=Docker";
    "origin=MongoDB,label=MongoDB";
    "origin=MySQL,label=MySQL";
    "origin=NodeSource,label=NodeSource";
    "origin=OpenResty,label=OpenResty";
    "origin=PostgreSQL Global Development Group,label=PostgreSQL";

Trying to use unattended upgrades but it doesn't seem to be updating anything, apt update says there are updates and when I attempted a dry run with unattended-upgrades it said no updates are available. Any possible fix to this?
APT::Periodic "";
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "5";

Result from apt-config dump | grep Periodic

Could you [edit] your post to show the output of apt-config dump | grep Periodic?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I've edited the post
